# An email with an embedded chart AND a datagrid using .net C#

Tags: .net, email, datagrid, charts

Requirement: An automated process that queries DB and builds a datagrid and a chart and sends off this report/info via email.

Issue: I am able to build the report with either the embedded image (chart) or the datagrid, not together. How do I get both the chart and the datagrid in the email?

code:

```
            MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtpservername", 25);
            m.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("vananthraman@abcd.com");
            m.To.Add("vananthraman@abcd.com");
            m.Subject = "This is a test";

            AlternateView plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, "text/plain");

            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<img src=cid:companylogo>", null, "text/html");



            System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource logo = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(path);
            logo.ContentId = "companylogo";

            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

            m.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
            m.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);



            //some_query is defined here
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(some_query, connection))
                    {


                        GridView gvwBmonitor = new GridView();
                        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        gvwBmonitor.DataSource = reader;
                        gvwBmonitor.DataBind();


                        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(new StringWriter(sb));
                        gvwBookingmonitor.RenderControl(hw);

                        m.Body = m.Body + sb.ToString();
                        AlternateView htmlView2 = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(sb.ToString(), null, "text/html");
                        m.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView2);
                        smtp.Send(m);

                    }
```

I only see the chart and not the grid. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the grid with the chart.
create list of linkedResources and each of those to the alternativeView.LinkedResources